# Como pegar um objeto em json com match

Tags: javascript, json, objetos

Bom dia, tenho um json com o seguinte formato:

```js
{
  "code_name_1001": "Antônio",
  "code_name_1002": "Luis",
  "code_name_1003": "Alice",
  "code_name_1004": "Julia"
}
```

minha dúvida está em como consigo pegar cada código e o nome associado ao código, por exemplo `//output`
`1001: Antônio`
`1002: Luis`

ao meu ver terei que usar match e replace para pegar ambos, porém não sei como executar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue criar um novo objeto com a chave sendo o código e o valor sendo o nome, para isso você pode utilizar um `for in` para percorrer as chaves do seu objeto dessa forma:

```
const obj = {
  "code_name_1001": "Antônio",
  "code_name_1002": "Luis",
  "code_name_1003": "Alice",
  "code_name_1004": "Julia"
}

let newObj = {}

for(o in obj) {
    const key = o.match(/\d*$/)[0]
    newObj[key] = obj[o]
}
```

Ao fazer o match, passo uma regex para obter somente os número:

- `\d`: Equivalente ao conjunto `[0-9]`, dessa forma você consegue obter os digitos presentes na `string`.
- `*`: Quantificador zero ou mais ocorrências, com ele é possivel capturar as ocorrências do conjunto `\d`.
- `$`: Significa fim do texto ou de uma linha, dessa forma conseguimos capturar somente os números que estão no final (no seu caso todos os números após a ultima ocorrência do caracter `_`).

Dessa forma `newObj` terá esse formato: `{ 1001: "Antônio", 1002: "Luis", 1003: "Alice", 1004: "Julia" }`, agora basta você pegar os valores, por exemplo:

```
Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => console.log(`${key}: ${newObj[key]}`))
```

Nesse caso estou usando o `Object.keys` para pegar as chaves do objeto e transforma-lo em um array, a saida seria assim: `[ "1001", "1002", "1003", "1004" ]`, após isso faço um `forEach` para percorrer o array gerado e fazer o output no console.

```js
const obj = {
  "code_name_1001": "Antônio",
  "code_name_1002": "Luis",
  "code_name_1003": "Alice",
  "code_name_1004": "Julia"
}

let newObj = {}

for(o in obj) {
    const key = o.match(/\d*$/)[0]
    newObj[key] = obj[o]
}

Object.keys(newObj).forEach(key => console.log(`${key}: ${newObj[key]}`))
```

Referências:

[Regex: Um guia prático para expressões regulares](https://medium.com/@alexandreservian/regex-um-guia-pratico-para-express%C3%B5es-regulares-1ac5fa4dd39f)

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: +1 Muito bom, mas pra explicação ficar melhor, acho que seria bom explicar essa Regex pra ficar mais claro par o AP ;).

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão, editei a resposta adicionando uma explicação para a regex e inserindo alguns links de referências.

Comment: Nossa, essa sem dúvidas foi uma ótima explicação, muito obrigado mesmo!!